# PHP zf2 can't match by routing when using "...index.php" but works OK with "...index.php/" ending with slash

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, http-status-code-404, matching, slash

I am unfamiliared with this framework and been having the following problem;

When I enter http://localhost/MyApp/public/index.php/ it routs OK to the index action of my index controller. 
But if I enter http://localhost/MyApp/public/index.php, changing only the ending slash, it doesn't work and shows 404 error:

> A 404 error occurred Page not found. The requested URL could not be
>   matched by routing.
>
> No Exception available

This is the code of my **module.config.php** routing:

```
<?php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

This is my Apache's **.htaccess** file:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Could you please tell me where i'm going wrong? Thank you in advance,

**Host configurations:**

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts:

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

127.0.0.1    localhost
```

C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# Use name-based virtual hosting.
#
##NameVirtualHost *:80
#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ##ServerName or ##ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ##ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

##<VirtualHost *:80>
    ##ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    ##DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ##ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ##ErrorLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-error.log"
    ##CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
##</VirtualHost>

#<VirtualHost *:80>
#    DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/zend/public"
#    ServerName zend
#    ServerAlias www.zend
#    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
#    <Directory "/xampp/htdocs/zend/public">
#      DirectoryIndex index.php
#      AllowOverride All
#      Order allow,deny
#      Allow from all
#    </Directory>
#</VirtualHost>
```

Adding the following code didn't work either, it redirects to http: //coolapp.localhost/xampp/ and shows xampp's home page.
It redirects to xamm's page whatever directory path I set.

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName coolapp.localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\CooltivateApp\public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
     <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\MyApp\public"
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Second test:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName coolapp.localhost
     DocumentRoot "C:\xampfgdp\htdfgdfgocs\tefgdgdfgApp\public"
     SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVd "development"
     <Directory "C:\xamdfgdpp\hdgftdocs\dltieAppdfgd\ddfpublic"
         DirectoryIndex index.php
         AllowOverride All
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does `http://localhost/MyApp/public/` work? Ideally you want to be setting up a virtual host that points to your public folder, as shown here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/ref/installation.html#apache-setup

Comment: "http://localhost/MyApp/public/" works OK. So does "http://localhost/MyApp/public".

Comment: Remove the `#` in front of the virtual host lines you added to the config (the `#` indicates a comment so currently your virtual host is commented out). You probably need `C:` at the start of the two xampp paths like in the other examples. Add a line to your hosts: `127.0.0.1    zend` since that's what you've used as the server name in your vhost. Then restart Apache and try opening http://zend/ in your browser.